# how use struct.pack for list of strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, numpy

I want to write a list of strings to a binary file. Suppose I have a list of strings `mylist`? Assume the items of the list has a `'\t'` at the end, except the last one has a `'\n'` at the end (to help me, recover the data back). Example: `['test\t', 'test1\t', 'test2\t', 'testl\n']`

For a numpy `ndarray`, I found the following script that worked (got it from here [numpy to r converter](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/06/30/#numpy_to_r_data_converter)):

```
binfile = open('myfile.bin','wb')
for i in range(mynpdata.shape[1]):
   binfile.write(struct.pack('%id' % mynpdata.shape[0], *mynpdata[:,i]))
binfile.close()
```

1. Does `binfile.write` automatically parses all the data if variable has `*` in front it (such in the `*mynpdata[:,i]` example above)? Would this work with a list of integers in the same way (e.g. `*myIntList`)?
2. How can I do the same with a list of string?

I tried it on a single string using (which I found somewhere on the net):

```
oneString = 'test'
oneStringByte = bytes(oneString,'utf-8')
struct.pack('I%ds' % (len(oneString),), len(oneString), oneString)
```

but I couldn't understand why is the `%` within `'I%ds'` above replaced by `(len(oneString),)` instead of `len(oneString)` like the `ndarray` example AND also why is both `len(oneString)` and `oneString` passed?

Can someone help me with writing a list of string (if necessary, assuming it is written to the same binary file where I wrote out the `ndarray`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `struct`. Simply join the strings and encode them using either a specified or an assumed text encoding in order to turn them into bytes.

```
''.join(L).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: would you know if there a size limit to joining? suppose my list of strings has 10,000 items where each string is typically 4-40 characters (I am using Python 3.4)?

Comment: However much process space you have left.